# Replace only one property of a model when passing as an argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to register a user, and my controller will accept a user model with their password, which I am hashing before saving.
Obviously there are a bunch of other properties of the model that I don't want to manually assign to an inline object.
Something like below, but before passing this object I want to break it down and change password from clear text to a hashed value, like so:

```
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
            iterationCount: 100000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
    }
```

and replace the plain text password in the model with {hashed}

```
public IActionResult Register(User user)
        {
                var context = new someContext();
                context.Users.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Manipulate `user` before `context.users.Add`. For example, `user.Password = hashed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest and most scalable approach is to use a view-model for getting data from the user, and manually build your model object in the action method.

View-model class:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set;}

    // You can add validation for this property for password security if needed
    public string PlainPassword { get; set; }
    
    // Add other properties that need to be received from user
}
```

Controller action method:

```
public IActionResult Register(UserViewModel userVM)
{
    string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: userVM.PlainPassword,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
        iterationCount: 100000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
    
    User user = new User { Username = userVM.username, Password = hashed };
    
    var context = new someContext();
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```